# Using a barcode Input as a variable without using input()

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, barcode

I am using a Barcode scanner to play albums using `python` and `Volumio`. The script I have written works if run with the `command line` but falls when I try to run it on `boot`. My code is below and I believe it is the `id = input()` line that is the problem.

Can anyone help me use the `Barcode` number as variable with out having to use the `input()`?

```
lp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')
while True:
    try:
        music = json.load(open("barc.txt"))
        id = ""
        socketIO = SocketIO('http://192.168.1.82', 3000)
        id = input()
        print(id)
        key = str(id)
        if key in music:
            band = music[str(id)]['band']
            album = music[str(id)]['album']
            print("%s is %s  %s" % (id,band, album))
            socketIO.emit("replaceAndPlay", {
                      "uri": "mnt/NAS/Music/%s/%s" % (band, album)})
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            print("%s is not in the system" % (id))
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ctrl c was pressed")
        break
```

Many Thanks

Comment: How to you have it scheduled to run on boot? `rc.local`?

Comment: Thank You for answering. Yes I have. It falls because it asks for a user input and as the `command line` isnt running it wont work.

Comment: So you would like the desktop to be booted up and then the audio to begin to play? Also would you post the `/var/log/syslog` so we may see what is happening?  Thanks.